# Temporary view is not working using CouchDb4J API in java

Tags: java, nosql, couchdb

```
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Session;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Database;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.Document;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.View;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.ViewResults;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.CouchResponse;
import com.fourspaces.couchdb.AdHocView;

public class temporaryViews 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{

    Session s = new Session("localhost",5984,"monil","monil",false,false);
    Database db = s.getDatabase("foodb");

// Running a view
       ViewResults resultAdHoc = db.adhoc("function (doc) {emit(null, doc);}");
       System.out.println(resultAdHoc.getResults().size());
  }
}
```

I tried to create temporary views by using above code ,i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at temporaryViews.main(temporaryViews.java:53)
```

Please suggest the solution

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Try  [EKTROP api](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp) that would help you.

Comment: i require to create view using Couchdb4j api, can anyone suggest me the solution

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue here (no views can be created). A temporary workaround is to update the server configuration. In the `couch.ini` file modify the authentication_handlers:

```
[httpd]
port=8008
authentication_handlers = {couch_httpd_oauth, oauth_authentication_handler},
    {couch_httpd_auth, null_authentication_handler},
    {couch_httpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}
```

The important one is **null_authentication_handler**, but beware: As https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authentication states, this is for developing purposes.

Hopefully, someone will find a real solution (for production environments).